# Import .sql file in Hive

Tags: sql, bash, hadoop, hive

I have the file named Hive_Tables.sql having the following code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HISTORY 
(
    ROWKEY STRING,
    ID STRING,
    START_TIME STRING,
    END_TIME STRING,
    VALUE DOUBLE
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
(
    "hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,VDS:ID,VDS:START_TIME,VDS:END_TIME,VDS:VALUE"
)
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "HISTORY");
```

How to import this file in Hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following bash command:

```
hive -f Hive_Tables.sql;
```